# Create Outlook MAPI Profile with IProfAdmin interface c++

Tags: c++, outlook, mapi

my knowledge in c++ is very limited but i'm trying however to use this sample code to create mapi profile programmatically:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306962

I compiled the code but the sample features are not enough for me as it only adds: ProfileName, MailboxName and Server,

i want to add as well RPC Proxy Server(Connect over HTTP) with all the settings like this window:

[image: Proxy Server image]

As i see in the profiler.cpp code the MailboxName and Server are in this portion:

```
// First, server name
ZeroMemory(&rgval[1], sizeof(SPropValue) );
rgval[1].ulPropTag = PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_SERVER;
rgval[1].Value.lpszA = szServer;

// Next, the mailbox name
ZeroMemory(&rgval[0], sizeof(SPropValue) );
rgval[0].ulPropTag = PR_PROFILE_UNRESOLVED_NAME; 
rgval[0].Value.lpszA = szMailbox;
```

and the tags/Properties are located in the EdkMdb.h file, so i tried to add this lines:

```
#define PR_PROFILE_RPC_PROXY_SERVER_FLAGS PROP_TAG( PT_LONG, pidProfileMin,0x2F)
#define PR_PROFILE_RPC_PROXY_SERVER_AUTH_PACKAGE (PT_LONG, pidProfileMin,0x1)
#define PR_PROFILE_RPC_PROXY_SERVER     PROP_TAG(PT_UNICODE, 0x6622001F)
```

Extend the `rgval` array

```
SPropValue      rgval[5];               // Property structure to hold values we want to set
```

then added this lines to the profiler.cpp

```
ZeroMemory(&rgval[2], sizeof(SPropValue));
rgval[2].ulPropTag = PR_PROFILE_RPC_PROXY_SERVER;
rgval[2].Value.lpszA = "mail.domain.com";

ZeroMemory(&rgval[3], sizeof(SPropValue));
rgval[3].ulPropTag = PR_PROFILE_RPC_PROXY_SERVER_FLAGS;
rgval[3].Value.ul = 0x1;

ZeroMemory(&rgval[4], sizeof(SPropValue));
rgval[4].ulPropTag = PR_PROFILE_RPC_PROXY_SERVER_AUTH_PACKAGE;
rgval[4].Value.ul = 0x2;
```

and change the 'Number of Properties to 5' here:

```
 if (FAILED(hRes = lpSvcAdmin->ConfigureMsgService(
        (LPMAPIUID)lpSvcRows->aRow->lpProps[iSvcUID].Value.bin.lpb, // Entry ID of service to configure
        NULL,                                                       // Handle to parent window
        0,                                                          // Flags
        5,                                                          // Number of properties we are setting
        rgval)))
```

**But it has no effect**, the Proxy setting is not configured in the new profile,

What i'm doing wrong or missing?

I'm Appreciating any help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create an RPC-over-HTTP connection, there are quite a few properties you need to set. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2014/01/17/how-create-outlook-profile-office-365.aspx

Things are a lot easier in Outlook 2016 - you essentially only need to supply the SMTP address: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2015/10/29/how-to-configure-an-outlook-2016-profile-using-mfcmapi.aspx

Comment: Thanks, set the all properties, still not working, the RPC over http is not checked, i'm on it for 10 hours, going nut, please help... btw, i'm not see any of this properties in outlook spy at all

Comment: Did you compare the good and the bad profiles using OutlookSpy (click IProfAdmin)?